# How to check Ram timing

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

Recently I bought DDR3 1600  4 * [4GB Rams](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231314), the manufacturer has mentioned the Ram timing as

```
Timing 9-9-9-24-2N
```

but the CPU-Z shows the timing as

```
11-11-11-28
```

[image]

SPD tab shows(All four slots shows identical data)

[image]

Is anything wrong in my bios or am I check at the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in SPD tab > Timings table > 4th column, in order for the RAM module to run at 9-9-9-24-2N, it must be in XMP-1600 profile. The BIOS automatically uses one of the JEDEC profiles, so you will have to go into BIOS settings and enable this profile for all modules.